# What does it means when one says the electric field is set up in the wire with a speed approaching the speed of light upon turning on the switch?

Tags: electromagnetism

When one says light comes on immediately when you turn on the switch of a flashlight cause the electric field is set up in the wire with a speed approaching the speed of light, what does exactly this sentence mean "electric field is set up in the wire with a speed approaching the speed of light" does the electric field travels from the source? If it doesn't how can it has a speed to begin with? Is there any sort of electromagnetic wave that originates upon turning the switch on that signals the farthest electron to move?

Answer (score 1):

> what does exactly this sentence mean "electric field is set up in the wire with a speed approaching the speed of light" does the electric field travels from the source?

Yes

> Is there any sort of electromagnetic wave that originates upon turning the switch on that signals the farthest electron to move?

Yes.

It takes time for an electromagnetic field to propagate whether that is in a wire, air, or any other medium.